# Is there a way to easily migrate my azure website to a different locale?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

not entirely programming related, but since the app running on Azure is asp.net MVC 5 I hope someone can help. Is there an easy way to migrate my MVC 5 app to a different locale. It's currently hosted in Western Europe, but it seems that Northern Europe is a better choice for a mainly UK service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just publish your code to new azure website and update dns to point new location (ip).
After a few hours or days you will just remove your old website.